# May I consider values in JavaScript's WeakMap to be weakly reachable?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, standards, specifications, weakmap

If I have two WeakMaps in javascript:

```
/**
 * @type {WeakMap.<Function, Provider>}
 */
const providerFtn = new WeakMap();

/**
 * @type {WeakMap.<Provider, Function>}
 */
const provider = new WeakMap();
```

and I place a Provider and its function in the WeakMaps...

```
function registerThingProvider(title, params) {
  const myProvider = new Provider(title);
  function factory() { new Thing(params); }

  providerFtn.set(factory, myProvider);
  provider.set(myProvider, factory);

  return myProvider;
}

let stronglyReachableProvider = registerThingProvider('fooBar', [ 3.14, null ]);
```

at this point, I would *hope* that both the provider and its function are strongly reachable.  My assumption is that a strongly reachable key makes both itself and its value unavailable for garbage collection.  The references in `providerFtn` and `provider` should be safe.

But, if I do a bunch of important work with my provider and then clear my one and only strong `stronglyReachableProvider` reference ...

```
await importantWork(stronglyReachableProvider);
stronglyReachableProvider = null;
```

Assume there are no other strong references to the objects outside of the WeakMaps.  Are `myProvider` and `factory` now eligible for garbage collection, or not?  It would be great if the value references in the WeakMaps were considered weakly reachable in this case, but I suspect WeakMap values would necessarily need to be implemented as strong references.

Comment: Could you maybe setup some sort of ticker inside of `factory` / `Provider` like in the example in here to test and see? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakRef